# Can I ask questions about JoliOs here

Tags: support

Can I ask questions about JoliOs here, I know in the FAQ they say I can't ask questions on Linux mint and the like but on their website (www.jolicloud.com) they say if I got any problem I should ask the ubuntu community.

http://help.jolicloud.com/entries/255104-i-get-an-error-when-i-update

what they say exactly in their site:

> Prerequisites to diagnose your issue
>
> If it still doesn't work, you can contact the Ubuntu community since
>   Joli OS is based on Ubuntu. Otherwise you might consider to backup
>   your local data and perform a clean reinstall.
>
> Provide as much detail as you can, including:
>
> ```
> The brand of your device
> The model of your device
> The feature affected (of course, update here)
> The error message you get (if applicable)
> A detailed description of your issue
> ```

Comment: Can you please explain where on the jolicloud site there are references to askubuntu?

Comment: @BrunoPereira Looks like they reference it on *every single* help page, this is serious. I sent a "Trademark Violation" report to Canonical since they don't have a disclaimer for use of "Ubuntu", also since this is misleading users to expect support from Ubuntu. example - http://help.jolicloud.com/entries/229205-Is-Joli-OS-compatible-with-my-machine-

Comment: @mateo_salta Did you research reporting it as a bug in their documentation first? I don't mean this judgmentally--but such a bug report should be filed if at all possible. If you've determined it's not possible, please let us know (with a link or some other explanation). Otherwise, I'll get to filing it eventually (and maybe someone else will file it first).

Comment: @EliahKagan I sent them a message first, it seems they have no area to "report as bug", so it was through the "Send a request" http://help.jolicloud.com/anonymous_requests/new - basically saying that it is an error to reference the Ubuntu community as support, and a link to this meta question. It doesn't seem they make the requests public (maybe need sign in) anyway it is http://help.jolicloud.com/requests/7220 , I'm not sure they even have a bug-tracker - http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=jolios

Comment: I tried contacting JoliOS through twitter and G+ but no response so far

Answer (score 6):

No, Jolicloud / Joli OS is neither Ubuntu nor an [official derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives) of Ubuntu, so questions about it here are off-topic. As an unofficial derivative, it is not supported here, though it has its own support resources, and is also on-topic on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

(A minority of questions that are *also* about Ubuntu or an official Ubuntu derivative would be on-topic here. For example, if you have Joli OS and you want to install Ubuntu, you could ask about that here, just as you could ask about how to install Ubuntu starting with Windows. So we would not close *every possible question* that contains the text "Joli OS," but questions that are not about Ubuntu or an official Ubuntu derivative are off-topic on main. Please see [our FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) for details, especially [the first section](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).)

Where do they say you should ask on Ask Ubuntu? I cannot find anything that says that [here](http://www.jolicloud.com/jolios/support) or [here](http://help.jolicloud.com/forums). If any official Joli OS help resource directs users to Ask Ubuntu, that should be reported as a bug in that help resource.

Comment: I am so sorry, In the website they say "contact Ubuntu Community since JoliOS is based on Ubuntu" which I think is not the same thing as askubuntu, may be we should close this question.

Comment: @PrabathSwarna Where on the website does it say that? Even that sounds like bad advice for them to give.

Comment: Looks like their tech solutins are putting that line on the bottom of their articles, http://help.jolicloud.com/entries/316531-I-have-an-issue-with-Flash-on-Joli-OS Maybe we need to get Canonical involved?

Comment: May be they are not aware it, maybe we should contact them before contacting canonicle

Comment: @PrabathSwarna I agree, especially considering that this is not really a trademark issue. This should really be reported as a bug in their documentation unless that is not possible. I've asked mateo_salta about that and I'll eventually get around to reporting it as a bug in their docs, but if you want to do it now, that would definitely be fine! If someone does report this as a bug in the Joli OS documentation, please comment here with a link so we know and can "join" the bug report (depending on what sort of bug tracking facility they use).

Comment: @EliahKagan This would be a trademark issue, because in http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy "Canonical owns a number of trademarks, including UBUNTU, KUBUNTU, EDUBUNTU and XUBUNTU. The trademarks are registered in both word and logo form. Any mark ending with the letters UBUNTU or BUNTU is sufficiently similar to one or more of the trademarks that permission will be needed in order to use it. This policy encompasses all marks, in word and logo form, collectively referred to as “Trademarks”." and further down under "Community advocacy"  it states the following -

Comment: " - there is no commercial intent behind the use
   - what you are referring to is in fact Ubuntu. If someone is confused into thinking that what isn't Ubuntu is in fact Ubuntu, you are probably doing something wrong
  -  there is no suggestion (through words or appearance) that your project is approved, sponsored, or affiliated with Ubuntu or its related projects unless it actually has been approved by and is accountable to the Ubuntu Community Council"
Looking at this it is clear trademark violation (unless they were approved, and I find nothing stating that on their pages)

Comment: @mateo_salta You seem to be saying "JoliOS is based on Ubuntu" sends the message that Joli OS is an *official* derivative (which would be a wrong message, as it's not an official derivative and not affiliated with the Ubuntu project or Canonical Ltd.). There may be a reasonable argument to that effect, but it's not obvious, and that's not the primary reason why the Joli OS documentation is wrong to say that.

Comment: @EliahKagan no, I'm saying that putting "If it still doesn't work, you can contact the Ubuntu community" on most of their help pages, is what is wrong.

Comment: @mateo_salta You think that implies official affiliation? Not every possible incorrect claim made about the Ubuntu community constitutes a trademark violation, and what constitutes a trademark violation is limited by applicable trademark *law* even when it falls under what the trademark *policy* disapproves of. Fundamentally, even if this is a trademark violation, that's *marginal* and *secondary* to the main thing wrong with it, which is that it sends people to wrong help resources instead of right ones.

Comment: I think that by casting this as *primarily* a trademark problem, you might manage to get Canonical more concerned about it, but this tactic will probably *prevent* most members of the two relevant communities from caring about the issue.

Comment: Either way, it needs fixed. And I doubt JoliOS will respond to the request, so it's up to Canonical what to do.

Comment: Is it wise to contact them via twitter with a link to this question. May be they have something to say on this matter too

Comment: @PrabathSwarna Contact Canonical via Twitter? Or Joli OS? Either way, sure, I don't see why not.

Comment: nobody takes this serious because of the duplicate tag :(